# Project Atomic registry not listening on 443

Tags: centos, docker, kubernetes, project-atomic

I'm using [the official documentation for quick-start](http://docs.projectatomic.io/registry/latest/registry_quickstart/administrators/index.html) to install [Atomic Registry](http://docs.projectatomic.io/registry/) on a Centos 7 atomic host, and it appears I can't access anything on port 443. (I also tried with a Fedora 23 atomic host, but, with about the same results)

Here's my system info

```
[centos@atomic1 ~]$ uname -a
Linux atomic1.localdomain 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 31 16:04:38 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[centos@atomic1 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

Here's the steps I took, other than the official documentation, the only added step I took was to disable selinux.

```
[centos@atomic1 ~]$ sudo atomic install projectatomic/atomic-registry-quickstart 192.168.122.161
[centos@atomic1 ~]$ sudo atomic run projectatomic/atomic-registry-quickstart 192.168.122.161
```

I've posted the [details of the install & run commands here at pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/70978).

I've also taken a look at the docker logs for the `origin` container, e.g. `sudo docker logs origin` and [I've posted those logs](http://www.pasteall.org/70977) as well.

I'm not well versed in Kubernetes, but I don't see the docker containers listening on any ports

```
[centos@atomic1 ~]$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7c55fe09fda7        cockpit/kubernetes                        "/usr/libexec/cockpit"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                            k8s_registry-console.e1e1af45_registry-console-1-cyrbk_default_a2d0a2a3-37a8-11e6-b418-525400f177e5_76e30266
ff7c6af11175        openshift/origin-docker-registry:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'DOCKER_R"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                            k8s_registry.3b6c8c75_docker-registry-1-5kva8_default_a2b1914e-37a8-11e6-b418-525400f177e5_e68c9f03
6f028b08118a        openshift/origin-pod:v1.3.0-alpha.1       "/pod"                   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                            k8s_POD.f8600130_registry-console-1-cyrbk_default_a2d0a2a3-37a8-11e6-b418-525400f177e5_b1982d98
ca1114728493        openshift/origin-pod:v1.3.0-alpha.1       "/pod"                   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                            k8s_POD.dfaa0123_docker-registry-1-5kva8_default_a2b1914e-37a8-11e6-b418-525400f177e5_739d21b2
21808267a1a1        openshift/origin                          "/usr/bin/openshift s"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            origin
```

Nor do I see any ports with netstat, a la:

```
[centos@atomic1 ~]$ netstat -atl | grep 443
```

And when I try to curl the local IP (and IP address I specified in the `atomic install` and `atomic run` commands), I get a connection refused

```
[centos@atomic1 ~]$ curl -k -v https://192.168.122.161
* About to connect() to 192.168.122.161 port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.122.161...
* Connection refused
* Failed connect to 192.168.122.161:443; Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.122.161:443; Connection refused
```

Which makes sense, seeing that it doesn't look like there's anything listening on 443.

So I went ahead and entered the `origin` container, and looked at the pods and the logs of a pod per [this extra administrative document](http://docs.projectatomic.io/registry/latest/registry_quickstart/administrators/system_configuration.html) about continuing the configuration of atomic registry, but, unfortunately I'm not sure what to do next.

```
[root@atomic1 origin]# oc get pods
NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
docker-registry-1-5kva8    1/1       Running   0          15m
registry-console-1-cyrbk   1/1       Running   0          15m
[root@atomic1 origin]# oc logs registry-console-1-cyrbk
INFO: cockpit-ws: Using certificate: /etc/cockpit/ws-certs.d/0-self-signed.cert
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that [just yesterday Project Atomic announced that there's a method to install using systemd](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/06/atomic-registry-systemd/).

I followed that method, using the [instructions from this openshift/origin project example](https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/master/examples/atomic-registry/systemd) about atomic registry.

Here's the snippet from that `README.md` that worked at the time of authoring this example:

---

#### Installation

1. Install

   ```
   sudo atomic install projectatomic/atomic-registry-install <hostname>
   ```
2. Start system services

   ```
   sudo systemctl start atomic-registry-master.service
   ```
3. Setup the registry. This script creates the oauth client so the web console can connect. It also configures the registry service account so it can connect to the API master.

   ```
   sudo /var/run/setup-atomic-registry.sh <hostname>
   ```

Comment: I installed the registry using the above method. when I access the console I get redirected to the Oauth server but after the redirect the registry console displays "Authentication failed" message.